# Oracle: How to find values present in an external list but not present in a column?

Tags: oracle, select, oracle10g

I have a table my_table with column my_column and a large list my_list of LONGs. I'd like to find all values that present in the my_list but not present in the my_table.my_column. How can I do that with SQL without repeating huge list of LONGs twice? Please shed some light as I'm Oracle beginner. Thank you.

#### EDIT:

my_list is just a short form of comma-separated values (1, 2, 3, 4), it's not a variable, just a way to call.

Answer (score 2):

If your list is constant, it's probably a good idea to store it in a reference table and to use a join as suggested to filter the records.

Otherwise you might reach 2 limits: the max length for a SQL statement and the maximum number of items that Oracle allows in a list. The latter can be solved by splitting your big list into smaller lists (my_column no in (...) and my_column not in (...)).

Comment: +1 sounds good. Thanks. Say I have 50 LONGs only, so how we can work with the list without using temporary table?

Comment: If your list is constant, you could create a pipelined function returning its values accessible from your SQL queries as if it was stored in a table

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
select * from my_table where my_column not in (my_list)
```

where my_list - comma-separated values list.
and how large is your list?

Comment: Sorry, I need to find those in my_list but NOT in my_column. You need to read more carefully.

Comment: A bit harsh, Viet.  And unless heximal has edited it since you commented, it SAYS "NOT in".  Also, berating him/her for using "select *" in a simple example is a bit over the top.

Comment: thanks, Tony) i meant exaclty what you said. but author is also right and i should be more careful when readning questions. and i'm going to be. promise)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_list
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

Comment: In Oracle it is "MINUS" not "EXCEPT", otherwise OK (assuming my_list is a table).